# List is null when checking for two conditions in where clause with boolean datatype in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, join, where-clause

In linq I'm facing a strange issue. Whenever I'm trying to specify two column with `bit datatype` in `where` clause it is returning **null**. But the thing is data is existing with that specific requirement in my table.

```
var data = (from PD in C.KYC_PERSONAL_DETAILS
                 join IMG in C.KYC_UPLOAD_DETAILS on PD.ACCOOUNT_NO equals IMG.ACCOOUNT_NO
                 where ( PD.FILEFLAG == false) && (IMG.IsVerify == true )
                 select new
                 {
                 PD_ACCOUNT_NO = PD.ACCOOUNT_NO,
                 PD_NAME = PD.NAME,
                 IMG_Name = IMG.Name
                 }.ToList();
      int count = data.Count(); //Here it shows 0 even though data exists in table.
```

Same query if I write in form of SQL Query then working and returning a Row.

```
select * from KYC_PERSONAL_DETAILS, KYC_UPLOAD_DETAILS 
        where KYC_PERSONAL_DETAILS.FILEFLAG = false 
        AND KYC_UPLOAD_DETAILS.IS_VERIFY= true

//Here it is returning a row.
```

I just want to know that is it possible to specifying two columns with boolean datatype and `&&` operator in where clause of **linq** or not ? If yes, then please suggest a way.

Comment: Check if your LINQ returns any record *without* the `where` and `select` parts.

Comment: If not, this could very well be a data types problem, as evident from your SQL statement (you're using string values instead of boolean).

Comment: It is working even if I use boolean in SQL.

Comment: Try my first suggestion.

Comment: And Yeah my LINQ is returning all records without `where` and `select` part. It even return a record if I keep query as it is but change any one of the column with `string` or `numeric` datattype.

Comment: The query is only giving problem whenever I use both columns with boolean datatypes. I can't understand why.?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at this line and check the data type of `FILEFLAG` and `IsVerify` properties (not db columns). I guess those would be `string`, not `bool`. If so, can you change your condition to `where ( PD.FILEFLAG == "false") && (IMG.IsVerify == "true" )`

Comment: @dotNET Checked it right now and it's `bool`. :(

Comment: Check it in the db too. I'm getting more and more convinced that this is a data types issue at the end.

Comment: Checked at both side. It's `boolean` in my model and `bit` in my DB. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141769/discussion-between-dotnet-and-chirag).

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using Entity Framework. Though my problem is solved and I posted solution to the problem as an answer. Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: I see it. But using `&` instead of `&&` is wrong in general. Most likely you are hitting a bug in the specific query provider (MySQL, SQLLite or other non SqlServer which works perfectly with `&&` conditions). It would be better for future readers if you include such details in your question/answer because otherwise it's misleading.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using `SQL Server 2008 R2` and I checked the same query on diffrent tables with boolean datatype but all are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and Error execution I found a way to make my LINQ Query working. Though I still don't know reason behind it but it's working now if I do it by any of following way. I'll update my answer after researching about the actual problem and logic behind this.

If I write the same query as

**1.**

```
var data = (from PD in C.KYC_PERSONAL_DETAILS
             join IMG in C.KYC_UPLOAD_DETAILS on PD.ACCOOUNT_NO equals IMG.ACCOOUNT_NO
             where PD.FILEFLAG == false
             where IMG.IsVerify == true 
             select new
             {
             PD_ACCOUNT_NO = PD.ACCOOUNT_NO,
             PD_NAME = PD.NAME,
             IMG_Name = IMG.Name
             }.ToList();
  int count = data.Count(); //Here it shows 1 data that exists in table.
```

**2.**

```
var data = (from PD in C.KYC_PERSONAL_DETAILS
             join IMG in C.KYC_UPLOAD_DETAILS on PD.ACCOOUNT_NO equals IMG.ACCOOUNT_NO
             where ( PD.FILEFLAG == false) & (IMG.IsVerify == true )
             select new
             {
             PD_ACCOUNT_NO = PD.ACCOOUNT_NO,
             PD_NAME = PD.NAME,
             IMG_Name = IMG.Name
             }.ToList();
  int count = data.Count(); //Here it shows 1 data that exists in table.
```

By writing the same query in case of boolean datatypes it is working well. 
I think there could be a problem because of using short-circuit operators.

> So, At the end either using `&` instead of `&&` or using two `where`
>   in LINQ query will work well whenever you want to deal with two
>   columns with `boolean` datatype. Using `&&` for other datatypes is alright but  in case of boolean it could create problems.

**UPDATE 1**

As a side note

> Though using **2nd** Option is ***not recommended*** as stated by Ivan in comments. Because I'm using `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` and Ivan claims that using `&&` in non sql DB is working fine and it's also possible that I might be facing a bug in SQL Server..